Difference performing a full text search in Lucene 2.4 and Lucene 3.1
I'm facing some issues while performing the same search in two different versions of Lucene (2.4 and 3.1) using the same index. I think that the problem is with the evolution of the Standard Analyzer class which I'm using in both versions.
Text to search: "Company, S.A."
LUCENE 2.4:
ParseQuery result:
text:"company sa"
N results.
LUCENE 3.1
ParseQuery result:
text:"company s.a"
0 results (expected same results that in version 2.4)
The funny thing is that when I'm searching using Lucene 2.4 it returns the results that I'm expecting while when using Lucene 3.1 version it doesn't.
I've searched how the phrase search works in Lucene and I've learned that when Lucene builds the index of the document it keeps the information of the words that belong to the document and the position of them in it. So, I could understand that the analyzer has changes in version 3.1 and the way that the terms are extracted is diferent but when it extracts the terms it should work the same way!
Another thing that I don't understand is that when I perform a similar search (deleting the dots) both versions return the same results.
Text to search: "Company, SA"
LUCENE 2.4:
ParseQuery result:
text:"company sa"
N results.
LUCENE 3.1
ParseQuery result:
text:"company sa"
same N results that version 2.4
So when Lucene indexes the term "s.a" (in version 3.1) what the hell is doing with it and why is not positioning it after "company" term?
